# Use the string functions left, right, mid and concatenate to create formulas to convert each of the the date columns to ISO standard dates

Tags: excel, string, function, concatenation, iso

How do I convert my date columns to ISO standard dates. Do I do this in the original column or Do I make a new column.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming the column in question is a recognisable date then right click the column the dates are in and select format cells In the number tab which is likely to be the one that is currently selected choose date, in my Excel ISO is the 7th date format. Alternatively choose custom and in the type box put yyyy-mm-dd